# Meter.call() pass variables

Tags: variables, meteor, methods, call

I'm trying to use Meteor.call() and pass two variables in to complete the method

```
Template.RegisterForm.events({
  'submit form': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var emailVar = event.target.registerEmail.value;
    var passwordVar = event.target.registerPassword.value;
    Meteor.call('registerUser', emailVar, passwordVar )
  }
});
```

However when I call the method, emailVar and passwordVar do not pass through.

```
registerUser: function (email, password) {
  var id = Accounts.createUser({
    email: email,
    password: password
  });
}
```

they come up undefined??

Comment: I should point out that it's a bad idea to send the user's credentials to the server this way. `Accounts.createUser` when used from the client encrypts the password before forwarding to the server. In your case you have the ability to capture unencrypted passwords as accounts are created.

Comment: ? Isn't my indention to encrypt a users password? account-password/meteor handles decryption? I have managed to login and save users to the db - my main problem is authenticating a user using roles at the moment.

Comment: I'm just recommending you just run `Accounts.createUser` on the client as it's intended to be used instead of creating a shim to run it on the server from the client.

Comment: Yeah I saw the documentation that said createUser is a client function however I wonder about security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the Meteor method fine,

```
var emailVar = event.target.registerEmail.value;
var passwordVar = event.target.registerPassword.value;
```

is likely your problematic code. `event.target` refers to the DOM element that initiated the event, in this case being the form. In turn, `registerEmail` and `registerPassword` *will* be undefined

See
https://jsfiddle.net/fqp3a1mq/ for an overview on using jQuery to grab your form data.

In the context of your specific issue, a clean solution is:

```
Template.form.events({
  'submit form'(event) {
    const $form = $(event.target);
    const formData = $form.serializeArray();
    const params = {};

    event.preventDefault();

    // loop over our form data and create a params object for our method
    formData.forEach(data => {
      params[data.name] = data.value;
    });

    Meteor.call('methodName', params);    
  },
});

Meteor.methods({
  methodName(params) {
    ...
  },
});
```

With this approach, if you have an input named `registerEmail`, then it will exist as `params.registerEmail` in your Meteor method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like this method, it seems like a bit more work but I like that it passes the info I need in a param.

Comment: Glad I could help :) @Ruegen, you should also look into [the check package](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-the-check-package/), it's built into Meteor. It means you can validate your `params` object in your method quite easily, which will help you write more robust code, and ensure your method is only taking valid form data.